# `make depends` magic in gnu make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple script (`depends.sh`) that generates the dependency file, and made some changes from the dependency file.

```
#!/bin/sh
#echo "## Got: $*"
CC="$1"
DIR="$2"
shift 2
case "$DIR" in
    "" | ".")
    $CC -MM -MG "$@" | sed -e 's@^\(.*\)\.o:@\1.d \1.o:@'
    ;;
    *)
    $CC -MM -MG "$@" | sed -e "s@^\(.*\)\.o:@$DIR/\1.d $DIR/\1.o:@"
    ;;
esac
```

The script is invoked from Makefile, this is excerpt from it.

```
DEP := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

# implicit rules

%.d: %.c
    ./depends.sh $(CC) `dirname $*.c` $(CFLAGS) $*.c > $@

-include $(DEP)

# Actual targets

depend: $(DEP)
```

What is interesting is that `make depends` does the following actions:

```
./depends.sh gcc `dirname src/hellomake.c` -Wall -Wno-unused-function -g -O  -Isrc  src/hellomake.c > src/hellomake.d
./depends.sh gcc `dirname src/hellofunc.c` -Wall -Wno-unused-function -g -O  -Isrc  src/hellofunc.c > src/hellofunc.d
cat depends.sh >depends 
chmod a+x depends
```

There is no `depends` target (only `depend` target), but it executes the depends target and even creates the depends script, and make it executable.

What's the magic behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two lines are from a built-in rule, which you could see if you used the "-p" option of make.  That looks something like

```
%.sh:

%: %.sh
#  commands to execute (built-in):
    cat $< >$@
    chmod a+x $@
```

It fires because your script is named "depends.sh".  The other two lines are run because make needs the $(DEPS) data.